# Why do I get all kinds of crazy characters in my emacs shell?

Tags: linux, emacs

When I open a shell in emacs (M-x shell) it has trouble displaying many "normal" characters.  I'm using Putty on Windows to connect to a linux server (a bash shell).  I'm running emacs within Putty with "emacs -nw".

What causes this and how can I fix it?

For example,

**Without emacs:**

```
username@server:~/so$ ls -a
.  ..  bar.txt  foo.txt
username@server:~/so$
```

**In emacs:**

```
username@server:~/so$ ls -a
^[[0m^[[01;34m.^[[0m  ^[[01;34m..^[[0m  bar.txt  foo.txt
^[[musername@server:~/so$
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing are ANSI control sequences for colouring output.

Emacs actually has a [number of different ways to access a shell](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/11/01/running-shells-in-emacs-overview/). They each have strengths and weaknesses.

Instead of `M-x shell`, try `M-x ansi-term`. This supports ANSI colours out of the box and is likely the closest to a "regular terminal", e.g. PuTTY, Konsole or Gnome Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'ansi-color-process-output)